# Aligning images next to eachother in a Signature

Tags: html, css, signature

I'm making a HTML signature for Gmail and having some alignment issues with the images. Previewing the code in DW and Chrome gives me something that looks like the first image. However when I copy this into Gmail it looks something like this:

[image: comparison between Gmail and Chrome]

Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>psdtowebPSD2648.psd</title>
    <link href="psdtowebPSD2648/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
         <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <a href="mailto:sarahhughes@spear-fish.com"> 
        <div id="SarahHughes"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SarahHughes.png"></div></a>
         <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <div id="BusinessDevelopmentM"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/BusinessDevelopmentM.png"></div>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <div id="spearfishlogov04"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/spearfishlogov04.png"></div>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <div id="divider"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/divider.png"></div>
         <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <a href="http://www.spear-fish.com/">
        <div id="SpearFishcom"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SpearFishcom.png"></div></a>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/spear_fish"> 
        <div id="twitter"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/twitter.png"></div></a>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dan-hooton/3/910/689"> 
        <div id="linkedin"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/linkedin.png"></div></a>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <div id="divider"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/divider.png"></div>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <a href="https://goo.gl/En7Cn9"> 
        <div id="ASpearfishRadleyHous"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ASpearfishRadleyHous.png"></div></a>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <div id="P443330555501M44"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/P443330555501M44.png"></div>
        <td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/100772955751868660892/posts"> 
        <div id="G"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/G.png"></div></a></div>
```

Comment: Ooops the beginning got cut short. Here is the comparison to what it looks like in DW/Chrome and then what it looks like in Gmail. http://gyazo.com/ac9f87897b5949323d1c364825574754

Comment: You start using TDs and Divs interchangibly why not stick to one instead of randomly mixing them up? Also format your HTML a bit better.

Comment: @TomKriek Yeah like I said I'm really not very knowledgeable. Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using tables to make everything properly aligned:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3><a href="mailto:sarahhughes@spear-fish.com"><img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SarahHughes.png"></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>
            <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/BusinessDevelopmentM.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/spearfishlogov04.png">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/divider.png">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SpearFishcom.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3><a href="https://goo.gl/En7Cn9"> 
                    <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ASpearfishRadleyHous.png"></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>
            <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/P443330555501M44.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3><a href="https://twitter.com/spear_fish"> 
       <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/twitter.png"></a>
 <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dan-hooton/3/910/689"> 
               <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/linkedin.png"></a>
 <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/100772955751868660892/posts"> 
       <img src="http://thegaminggeek.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/G.png"></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```